# Minecraft DNS SRV record correct setup

Tags: domain-name-system, gameserver, srv-record

I am trying to setup DNS SRV records on my domain so that my players are able to connect without entering the IP address and port of my Minecraft server.

I've successfully created an A record and it's pointing to the right IP. Now, I have to create a SRV record to point to right port, but all my tries ended with connection refused in the Minecraft game client.

The service that I want to reach is sitting on 93.91.250.130:27296 and I can successfully connect to it by IP address and port.

My Current setup is:

A record

```
Domain         Target
mine.rlnd.cz   93.91.250.130
```

SRV record

```
Domain                    Target         Priority    Weight    Port
_minecraft._tcp.rlnd.cz   mine.rlnd.cz   5           5         27296
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've never touched anything Minecraft-related but, zow, I'm surprised and pleased to learn that it uses SRV records! Maybe someday SRV records will actually become useful!

Comment: @EvanAnderson in a way it shouldn't be too surprising: Having support for SRV spread to all Minecraft clients required a change to one application. Meanwhile, having several servers on different ports on the same IP was common, so there was an immediate benefit. Compare with the idea of using SRV for HTTP; the number of clients that would have to change, and the small immediate benefit. The benefits of open protocols are great, but this is one case where there being only one implementation has the advantage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The SRV record should be created for `_minecraft._tcp.mine.rlnd.cz`, not `_minecraft._tcp.rlnd.cz`.

More Info:

SRV records are not always directly under the domain name - `_service._proto.domain.com`.
I think this may be a fairly common misconception with SRV, partly because the poster-child application for it, Exchange/Outlook, uses the domain portion of your email address and a lot of information online generally tells you that 'you need an SRV record for your domain'.

If you enter `a.b.domain.com` into an SRV aware application, it will lookup the SRV record for `_service._proto.a.b.domain.com`.