# HAProxy in front of logstash broken pipe

Tags: haproxy, logstash, elk

I'm setting up ELK stacks with loadbalancing. Haproxy works fine for ES and Kibana but I'm having issues with Logstash.

Here's the haproxy configuration:

```
frontend logstash
   bind 0.0.0.0:5000
   mode tcp
   option tcpka
   option tcplog
   log global
   acl epa hdr_beg(host) -i epa-log
   acl tgops hdr_beg(host) -i tgops-log
   use_backend epa_log if epa
   use_backend tgops_log if tgops

backend epa_log
   mode tcp
   server elk01 elk01.example.org:5001 check
   server elk02 elk02.example.org:5001 check
   server elk03 elk03.example.org:5001 check

backend tgops_log
   mode tcp
   server elk01 elk01.example.org:5002 check
   server elk02 elk02.example.org:5002 check
   server elk03 elk03.example.org:5002 check
```

As you can see, im trying to have 1 frontend serving port 5000 and redirecting to a different port based on the url of the source.

If I do a netcat directly to the server it works perfectly

```
nc elk01 5001 -vv < /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

But if I use the haproxy frontend, it fails with a broken pipe error.

```
nc tgops-log 5000 -vv < /var/log/httpd/error_log
Ncat: Version 6.40 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )
libnsock nsi_new2(): nsi_new (IOD #1)
libnsock nsock_connect_tcp(): TCP connection requested to 10.129.10.2:5000 (IOD #1) EID 8
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: CONNECT SUCCESS for EID 8 [10.129.10.2:5000]
Ncat: Connected to 10.129.10.2:5000.
libnsock nsi_new2(): nsi_new (IOD #2)
libnsock nsock_read(): Read request from IOD #1 [10.129.10.2:5000] (timeout: -1ms) EID 18
libnsock nsock_readbytes(): Read request for 0 bytes from IOD #2 [peer unspecified] EID 26
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: READ SUCCESS for EID 26 [peer unspecified] (8192 bytes)
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: WRITE SUCCESS for EID 35 [10.129.10.2:5000]
libnsock nsock_readbytes(): Read request for 0 bytes from IOD #2 [peer unspecified] EID 42
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: READ SUCCESS for EID 42 [peer unspecified] (8192 bytes)
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: WRITE SUCCESS for EID 51 [10.129.10.2:5000]
libnsock nsock_readbytes(): Read request for 0 bytes from IOD #2 [peer unspecified] EID 58
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: READ SUCCESS for EID 58 [peer unspecified] (8192 bytes)
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: WRITE SUCCESS for EID 67 [10.129.10.2:5000]
libnsock nsock_readbytes(): Read request for 0 bytes from IOD #2 [peer unspecified] EID 74
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: READ EOF for EID 18 [10.129.10.2:5000]
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: READ SUCCESS for EID 74 [peer unspecified] (8192 bytes)
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: WRITE SUCCESS for EID 83 [10.129.10.2:5000]
libnsock nsock_readbytes(): Read request for 0 bytes from IOD #2 [peer unspecified] EID 90
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: READ SUCCESS for EID 90 [peer unspecified] (8192 bytes)
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: WRITE SUCCESS for EID 99 [10.129.10.2:5000]
libnsock nsock_readbytes(): Read request for 0 bytes from IOD #2 [peer unspecified] EID 106
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: READ SUCCESS for EID 106 [peer unspecified] (8192 bytes)
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: WRITE SUCCESS for EID 115 [10.129.10.2:5000]
libnsock nsock_readbytes(): Read request for 0 bytes from IOD #2 [peer unspecified] EID 122
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: READ SUCCESS for EID 122 [peer unspecified] (8192 bytes)
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: WRITE SUCCESS for EID 131 [10.129.10.2:5000]
libnsock nsock_readbytes(): Read request for 0 bytes from IOD #2 [peer unspecified] EID 138
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: READ SUCCESS for EID 138 [peer unspecified] (8192 bytes)
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: WRITE ERROR [Broken pipe (32)] for EID 147 [10.129.10.2:5000]
Ncat: Broken pipe.
```

If I check the TCP logs, I find that it somehow won't reach the backend, throws a NOSRV

```
 logstash logstash/<NOSRV> -1/-1/0 0 SC 15/0/0/0/0 0/0n 10.129.10.82:50724
```

I've tried different HAProxy options, like `clitcpka`, balance source, using only 1 backend and more but none resolves this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `mode tcp` and match headers. `mode tcp` means don't treat the connection as HTTP and just pass the raw bytes through.

Comment: So here i'd have no choice but to make a diffrent "listen" for every port?

Comment: Dispatching connections to different backends depending on the hostname which the client connected to is impossible to do on the TCP layer. - https://serverfault.com/questions/643131/proxying-tcp-by-hostname